# Multiple Meshes Sharing 1 UV space

Tags: mesh, uv

I have a scene made up of rows of cubes stacked on top of each other.

I want to add an image texture to all the front faces of the cube stack (the image is not seamless it is a picture).

I joined all the cubes to 1 mesh then UV unwrapped them then painstakingly aligned each front face to each other then added the image texture. All good up to this point however when I unjoin the meshes the image texture is all messed up.

What I am trying to achieve is a simulation of a wall with picture on the front been smashed by a smashing ball and the individual cubes sent flying off with there part of the image texture on it.

My question is can this be achieved & what is the best method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Had you projected from the view when unwrapping (while in Front Ortho) you wouldn't have needed to do all that painstaking alignment.

Comment: Thanks I was unaware of the Projected from view option, I wish I had known about this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by creating and texturing your wall before splitting it up into different pieces.

After you created your wall you can use the cell fracture add-on to break your wall down. For smashing your wall with a wreckingball this would create the desired effect.

For an in-depth tutorial of this method see the youtube vid made by CG Geek:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUUi2AdLtmk

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I have not tried it yet but after watching the video it is what I am trying to achieve but this is even better.  I cant mark as answered as I only have Add Comment & Answer Your Question options available